# Is it bad that C++0x's lambda expressions don't have a named type?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++11

I've been reading a bit about lambda expressions on the internet recently and it seems to me that C++0x's lambda expressions will not have a single type (or types) that will bind exclusively to lambda expressions -- in other words, lambda expressions will only match template arguments or `auto` arguments/variables. What happens, as described [here](http://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2009/08/03/hello-lambdas-c-0x-a-quick-guide-to-lambdas-in-c/), is that

> Compilers that support lambdas will
>   create a unique anonymous functor type
>   for each lambda expression

My question is, is that a bad thing? Wouldn't it make sense to have some keyword that matches only to lambda expressions, e.g. `lambda`, which would work as follows

```
void f(std::function<int(int)> func)
{
     func(2);
}

template<typename T>
void g(T func)
{
     func(2);
}

void h(lambda func)
{
     func(2);
}

int main()
{
    int fpointer(int);
    struct { int operator()(int var) { return var; } } functor;

    f(fpointer); //ok (actually a linker error, but for the sake of example)
    f(functor); //ok
    f([](int var) { return var; }); //ok

    g(fpointer); //ok
    g(functor); //ok
    g([](int var) { return var; }); //ok

    h(fpointer); //error -- function pointer isn't a lambda expr
    h(functor); //error -- functor isn't a lambda expr
    h([](int var) { return var; }); //ok

    return 0;
}
```

To be honest, I actually can't see the usefulness of this (especially given that `auto` accepts lambda expressions, so one could then assign a lambda to a variable), but it still doesn't sit right with me that lambda expressions are anonymous types and cannot be bound specifically to just one particular type (to the exclusion of all others).

In essence, my question is, is it fine that lambda expressions are anonymous (both in terms of utility -- does the lack of a `lambda` type devoid us of some functionality -- and philosophically -- does it really make sense that lambda expressions always have the 'type' `auto`)?

Comment: It slightly sounds like you are not aware that you can accept lambda expressions using `std::function<int(int)>` too.

Comment: I was, however since the general functionality matches how `auto` works (afaik), I thought it unnecessary to add *another* set of example functions/function calls (but it's still good to mention, so thanks litb)

Comment: I think there's a misunderstanding about auto. auto can't be used as a parameter type in a function. It's not a type. auto just says "deduce the type from the initializer because I'm too lazy or just unable to name the type".

Comment: I've changed the `auto` parameter in that case. I am still confident that you can do `auto = [](int a) { ... };` however (...right? ;) )

Comment: the whole purpose of `op()` was that you don't have to worry about the functor type. now if you restrict something to only lambdas (surely i think implementations will provide some `__is_lambda` metafunction or something you could use with `enable_if`), what sense would it make to get rid of the ability to acccept function pointers etc. I don't see any and i believe there is no sense in it.

Comment: I mean that's really what I'm getting at litb, does it make sense to restrict just to lambda expressions. It seems the general consensus is no, and I thought that way as well, but I wanted to ask anyway and see what people think.

Comment: I heard they want to forbid lambda expressions within `decltype` :) Maybe sfinae could be (ab)used to use `decltype` on `*(T*)0` or something similar (not sure whether they forbid it on expressions having lambda type, or only on the literal itself...) :)

Comment: What is "lambda" supposed to be? A type? Something that turns the function taking a "lambda" implicitly into a template? How would it be any different from std::function<> or a "normal" template?

Comment: @litb: No, that's not how it works. If you write "auto f = []{return 23;};" you can, of course, use sizeof and decltype on f. Just not directly with a lambda expression because that would make no sense because every lambda expression has its own unique type.

Comment: `lambda` in theory would accept *only* lambda expressions as parameters. That would differ from templates insofar as that they will accept any type that will compile (e.g. a lambda expression, a functor with operator(), a function pointer). However, since you can have any multitude of lambda signatures (i.e. one that takes one int, one that takes two, etc), an error would be thrown by the compiler if the passed lambda expression cannot be called in the way that `h()` calls it (this mechanism would be similar to templates)

Comment: And sorry, yes, it would be a type. You could assign a variable in the manner such as `lambda var = [](...) {...};`

Comment: It cannot be a type if you want the behaviour you descibed earlier with "like a template". To be honest, I don't see any value in either idea -- be it implicit templates or just a shorthand for function<void(double)>.

Comment: Yeah you're right, I just realized it as I typed it out. Anyway as you mention I was just interested in figuring out if there would be any utility in the idea.

Comment: Here's an updated not-yet-accepted recent proposal that might interest you. It mentions implicit conversions to plain function pointers. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2009/n2954.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lambdas are independent types. The code

```
void h(lambda func)
{
     func(2);
}
```

doesn't make any sense because lambdas don't have runtime polymorphism. Recall that a lambda is the equivalent of

```
struct unique_name
{
    return_type operator()(Arg1 a1, Arg2 a2, ... , Argn an)
    {
        code_inside_lambda;
    }
}
```

Which is itself a unique type. The code above would be the same as saying

```
void h(class C)
{
     C(2);
}
```

Which also makes no sense even if we assure that C has `operator()`. You need a template:

```
template<typename T>
void g(T func)
{
     func(2);
}

int main()
{
    g([](int x){return x + 2;});
}
```

Comment: You make a good point about the idea of having `void h(class C)`, however I *can* do `void h(functor_name C)` which will only match parameters of that particular functor type. I can't do the same with a lambda expression.

Comment: If you need to refer to a particular lambda by name, you should instead define it the old way using a `struct`. A lambda expression is, by definition, anonymous.

Comment: That's a good point, if you need to specialize to lambda expressions (even though it'd provide no functionality) you're probably using them incorrectly anyway (and would be going against the theory of lambda epxressions). Plus, as I mentioned and as everyone else has mentioned, there would just probably be no utility to it (though litb's right that someone will add a nonstandard compiler extension for it anyway). I've accepted this answer

Answer (score 3):

I see no reason to differentiate function types based on whether the function has a name or not. Lambda functions are just a shorthand, allowing you to define a convenience function easily. Name or no name, the behaviour of the function when called is the same.

Think of it this way. An early version of your software has a predicate defined as an anonymous function. Over time, requirements get more complex, and your predicate gets more complex too - and maybe you need to call it from more than one place. The sensible thing to do is to refactor so that you have a named function.

There's no reason why the called function (the one that calls the predicate) should care about that. Simple or complex, named or anonymous - it's still just a predicate function.

One minor issue is that of closures - I haven't checked, but with a bit of luck, C++ will get nested named functions with closures as well as lambdas.